# How to get the square of loops in C

Tags: c

Using a do...while() loop need to continuously scan for random integers that will be inputted by the user and print out its square, separated in each line. Once the inputted value is 0, it will still print out its square value but should then terminate the loop afterwards.

this is the sample input:
2,
6,
0

this is the sample output:
4,
36,
0

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int a;
  int num;
  int b;

  do {
    scanf("%d", &a);
  } while (a != 0);

  while (a > num) {
    num++;

    if (num == a) {
      b = num * a;
      printf("%d", b);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). What is the value of `a` once the first loop ends?

Comment: still dont work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It would improve the question if you would explain what you are seeing going wrong, and what you have tried, so far, to debug it.  You might also find this link helpful: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  Some of it may be overkill for this small program, but it will help you in the future.  Rubber duck debugging and stepping through the code, however, work for the smallest programs and should be sufficient to find the bugs in the code you posted.  Even if someone has already answered below.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "Don't work" is not a usefull description of your problem. The question itself does not contain any description at all. For future questions please always include your expected output, your real output, what you have done to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int a;
  do {
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d\n", a * a);
  } while (a != 0);
}
```

Comment: check out the sample input and output provided

Comment: you may like to provide input without *comma*. Just type input 2 6 0

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer. Stack Overflow is for answering questions, not for providing code to students without effort.

Comment: what are saying without effort? i am basically asking whats wrong with my code

Comment: @CLEID I believe that Eric is commenting on the quality of the answer, not the question.  That said, to be a successful programmer, it is very important to develop debugging skills, so you can figure out yourself what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue I can see in your code is that the variable `num` is not initialized to a specific value, so `num > a` is meaningless and the second loop won't work correctly.

The second is that the `a` variable can store only one value at a time and that's why the value users enter will be replaced with the last value they entered, and finally, you can only print the square of a number out.

A very simple solution is that you can want the user to enter as many numbers as they want (and also 0 as the last number), press Enter at the end. After that, only call `printf` to print the square of them on the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("%d ", a * a);
    } while(a != 0);
    return 0;
}
```